# Follow the tutorial to the 'Tab Completion' and get error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tutorial 3.5 Tab Completion: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem

I typed in the code below and received the error:

$ roscd roscpp_tut<<< now push the TAB key >>>

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'

I am confused...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298085/follow-the-tutorial-to-the-%27tab-completion%27-and-get-error/) by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-20**:
Is that command literally what you typed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only type `roscd roscpp_tut`, then hit the Tab key on your keyboard. Then your terminal will fill in the rest of the package's name.

---

Originally posted by [etappan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22710/etappan/) with karma: 53 on 2018-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on 2018-07-20**:
Thank you! Guess I misunderstood the tutorial